# Set cookies in a php cgi enviroment without using php api

Tags: php, cgi, cookies

How can I use cookies in a php CGI Enviroment without using any api functions from PHP?

Comment: no not really schould be a simple help how to realize such a thing.

Comment: you should format the question as an actual question, the post the answer as an answer to your own question.  that is the appropriate way of doing this.

Comment: ph thank you i will do so ...

Comment: I don't know about others, but I downvote questions where the person asking a question asks it solely to answer their own question.

Comment: @Bemrose, from the stack overflow FAQ: It's also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own programming question, but pretend you're on Jeopardy: phrase it in the form of a question.

Comment: I think this is not the right way. If you have a problem and search the web an find on three different places your answer and you put it here so that others don't need to search half an hour and find all Information on a centralized place, why should this be a downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok you want to setup cookies with php in a CGI Enviroment?

Copy the code and name it to whatever.cgi and make it executable

```
#!/usr/bin/php
function set_cookie($cookiename,$cookievalue,$cookietime){
   echo 'set-cookie: '.$cookiename.'="'.$cookievalue.'"; max-age="'.$cookietime.'";'."\n";  
}
```

The \n at the end of the line is a must. Or you will run into trouble :)
Now let's set a cookie:

```
set_cookie("foo","bar",60)
```

Sets the Cookie with the Name foo to the Value bar. Expires in 60 seconds.

Now you can start with the HTML Header.

```
echo "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";
echo "<html>\n";
echo "<head>\n";
echo "<title>whatever</title>\n";
echo "</head>\n";
echo "<body>\n";
```

If you want to delete the cookie, set the max-age to zero

```
function set_cookie($cookiename){
   echo 'set-cookie: '.$cookiename.'="0"; max-age="0";'."\n";  
}
```